# Calling a function c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This piece of code is suppose to get a letter from the user in 'alphabet' and return the corresponding letter in mapsTo. eg 'A' will result in 'Z'

```
class Program
      {
        static void Main()
        {
        }
        char[] alphabet = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }; 
        char[] mapsTo = { 'Z', 'Y', 'X' };
        public string changeLetter(char input)

        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (char c in alphabet)
            {
                if (c == input)
                {
                    return mapsTo[i].ToString();
                }
               i++;
            }
            return default(char).ToString();
        }
    }
    }
```

I know that the code below will store the user input, but I am unsure what is next, and where in the program that code should be placed

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
            userInput= Console.ReadLine;
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `Dictionary<char, char>`? That would be a simpler way of mapping...

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I highly suspect this is homework and he was given what he has so far.

Comment: Your return type should be char

Comment: @JonSkeet I am fairly new, I will check out the dictionary, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be the Main-method i guess. When you run the application the Main-method will be called. If you put your writeline and userInput variable there, you would be able to call your changeLetter method with userInput as argument. Just store the return statement as a new variable and go from there

Comment: string userInput;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(userInput);
            Console.ReadLine();                                                                                So something like this Im guessing, how do I call the changeLetter?

Comment: Your changeLetter method has a return statement, so you should make a variable and assign it to the return statement using the assignment operator. When you write userInput = Console.ReadLine(), you call the ReadLine() method from the Console class and assigns your userInput variable to the returned statement. Just do the same for someVariable and changeLetter()

Comment: thank you, I understand what youre saying, but not sure how to put that into theory, can you demonstrate ?

Comment: string output = changeLetter(userInput);
Console.WriteLine(output);

Comment: changeLetter takes char as an argument and youre giving it a string. Change userInput to be of type char instead of string

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses:

```
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Also, your main code goes **in** `Main()`, like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // code here
}
```